# How to save a *multipart.FileHeader type to gorm postgres db

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

am trying to upload an image using the 'content-type: multipart/form-data;
it works but am having troubles saving it to the database using GORM

```
type Avatar struct{
Image        *multipart.FileHeader `form:"image"`

}
```

i tried to make the image field to type bytes but it throws an error

```
unsupported data type: net/textproto.MIMEHeader: Table not set, please set it like: db.Model(&user) or db.Table(\"users\")
```

my model

```
type ImageUpload struct {
Image        byte`json:"image"`
}
```

and how do you convert the *multipart.FileHeader i.e image to BLOB

Comment: Please check out how to save and read custom data types:
https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html#content-inner